# XAudio2 - playing only a part of the audio

Tags: c++, audio, directx, xaudio2

I am trying to play mp3/wma using xaudio2. I managed to use the Media Foundation Source Reader object to do the decoding. My problem is, it is not playing the full audio; I could get only a part of the audio played.

What I am trying to do is, get the next sample from IMFSourceReader and submit this as the next buffer of sourcevoice. This is repeated util all the data is read from IMFSourceReader.

```
 while (true)
{
    DWORD dwFlags = 0;

    // Read the next sample.
    hr = pReader->ReadSample(
        (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM,
        0, NULL, &dwFlags, NULL, &pSample );


    if (dwFlags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_CURRENTMEDIATYPECHANGED)
    {
        printf("Type change - not supported by WAVE file format.\n");
        break;
    }
    if (dwFlags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_ENDOFSTREAM)
    {
        printf("End of input file.\n");
        break;
    }

    if (pSample == NULL)
    {
        printf("No sample\n");
        continue;
    }

    // Get a pointer to the audio data in the sample.

    hr = pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pBuffer);

    if (FAILED(hr)) { break; }


    hr = pBuffer->Lock(&pAudioData, NULL, &cbBuffer);

    if (FAILED(hr)) { break; }


    // Make sure not to exceed the specified maximum size.
    if (cbMaxAudioData - cbAudioData < cbBuffer)
    {
        cbBuffer = cbMaxAudioData - cbAudioData;
    }

    // Write this data to the output file.
    hr = WriteToFile(hFile, pAudioData, cbBuffer);

    int audioBufferLength = cbBuffer;


    if (FAILED(hr)) { break; }
    SubmitBuffer(pAudioData, audioBufferLength);
    // Unlock the buffer.
    hr = pBuffer->Unlock();



    pAudioData = NULL;

    if (FAILED(hr)) { break; }

    // Update running total of audio data.
    cbAudioData += cbBuffer;

    if (cbAudioData >= cbMaxAudioData)
    {
        break;
    }

    SafeRelease(&pSample);
    SafeRelease(&pBuffer);
}

void AudioDecoder::SubmitBuffer(byte *pAudioData, int audioBufferLength)
{

    byte * pAudioBuffer = new byte[audioBufferLength];
    CopyMemory(pAudioBuffer, pAudioData, audioBufferLength);
    if (pAudioBuffer != nullptr)
    {
     // Create an XAUDIO2_BUFFER for submitting audio data
     XAUDIO2_BUFFER buffer = {0};
     buffer.AudioBytes = audioBufferLength;
     buffer.pAudioData = pAudioBuffer;
     buffer.pContext = pAudioBuffer;
     HRESULT hresult = m_pSourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer(&buffer);
    }

}
```

After this I am calling m_pSourceVoice->Start(). This will start the audio, but not playing the full audio. Do I need to add anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This loop doesn't look like it accounts for if any buffers have been completed before submitting more, so could be running into the limit of XAUDIO2_MAX_QUEUED_BUFFERS. Can you create a counter on your while loop to see how many buffers are submitted to the source voice?

If you've hit a limit you could start playback before fully decoding the file and submit additional buffers via source voice callbacks.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415769(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes you were right... I was not taking into account XAUDIO2_MAX_QUEUED_BUFFERS and that caused the problem. Thank you very much